# Code coverage help! I need help writing the test class for a trigger

Tags: code-coverage, code

My issue is that although my test class (below) passes, I am getting 0% test coverage on the trigger. Not sure why?!!

Below are my trigger and test class:

Here's my trigger:

```
trigger AgreementAddQuoteId on echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c (before update)

{
  list<Id> oppyIds = new list<Id>{};

  for(echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c e : Trigger.new)
  {
      oppyIds.add(e.echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c);
  }

 map<Id,Quote> qtMap = new map<Id,Quote>([SELECT Id FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppyIds ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1]);

 for (Id idKey : qtMap.keyset ())

  for(echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c e : Trigger.new)
  {
     Quote q = qtMap.get(idKey);
      If(e.echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c != null)
      {
      e.Quote__c = q.Id;
      System.debug(q.Id);
      System.debug(e.Id);
      System.debug(e.echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c);
      }
  }
}
```

And my Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class TestAgreementAddQuoteId {

    private static testMethod void test() 
    {
        Map <String ,ID> profiles = new Map<String,ID>();
        List<Profile> ps = [select id, name from Profile where name='System Administrator'];
        Map<String,ID> roles = new Map<String, ID>();
        List<UserRole> urs = [select id, name from UserRole where  DeveloperName = 'XXXX'];

        for (Profile p : ps){
          profiles.put(p.name,p.id);
        }
        for (UserRole u : urs){
          roles.put(u.DeveloperName,u.id);
        }

        User testUser1 = new User (firstname='test',
                                   lastname='User5',
                                   Alias= 'user1', 
                                   Email='testUser1@test.com', 
                                   Username='testUserlulu5@test.com', 
                                   CommunityNickname='test1',
                                   profileid = profiles.get('System Administrator'),
                                   languagelocalekey='en_US',
                                   localesidkey='en_US',
                                   timezonesidkey='America/New_York', 
                                   userroleid = roles.get('XXXX'),
                                   emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                                   Phone='5851234567');
        insert testUser1;

        User tu1 = [select id from User where name ='test User5'];

        Account a1 = new Account (name='Parent Account1',Industry='Finance');
        insert a1;

        Contact ct1 = new Contact (FirstName = 'testContactFirst',LastName= 'testContactLast',
        Ownerid=tu1.id, Phone='5555555555', Email='email@email.com');
        insert ct1;

        Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity (CloseDate = Date.today()+1, Name = 'opportunity test', StageName = 'SQL', LeadSource = 'Self-Developed',
        Description = 'Test Description', AccountId = a1.Id);
        insert o1;

        Quote q1 = new Quote (OpportunityId = o1.Id, ContactId = ct1.Id);
        Quote q2 = new Quote (OpportunityId = o1.Id, ContactId = ct1.Id);

        test.startTest();

        echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c agr1 = new echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c (echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c = o1.Id);
        insert agr1;

        test.stopTest();

        echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c testagr =[SELECT Quote__c,echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c from echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c WHERE Id = : agr1.Id];
        System.assertEquals(q2.id, testagr.Quote__c);
        System.assertEquals(o1.id, testagr.echosign_dev1__Opportunity__c);
      }

}
```

Comment: Using an update of 'agr1', I was able to raise the coverage level to 54%! 46% to go..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is on `before update` for `echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c`, but in your test class you are only inserting agr1. So the trigger never runs.